# Extending a line in the Table

Tags: tables, rules, arrays, multicolumn, data-structures

I wish to have a Table setting like the following graph with an extra line inserted between a and b. Namely, I wish to extend the line separating 1, 4 and 2, 5 to the line separating a and b.

> The figure is the output from my code, however, it does not have an extra line inserted separating a, 1, 4 and b, 2, 5. How to do that? Is there an elegant way to do it? My code is rather ugly attached below. There may be an excellent beautiful way to do it.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[aps]{revtex4} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}


  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c||c|c }
      & $K$ & $H$ \\ \hline\hline
    A \vline~~$a$ & 1& 4    \\ \cline{2-3}
    \;B \vline~~ $b$ & $2$ & $5$\\ \hline
    C& $3$ &  $6$\\   
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: table]

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c|C||C|C }
      \multicolumn{2}{c||}{} & K & H \\ \hline\hline
      A & a & 1& 4    \\ \cline{2-4}
      \;B & b & 2 & 5\\ \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{c||}{C}& 3 &  6\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that it is not recommended to typeset tables like this. This many rules make the table look crowded and does not help readers parse it easily. Indeed, professional-quality tables do not typically include any vertical rules, use horizontal rules sparingly and use variations in weight rather than doubling. They also include rather more space to help separate distinct cells. The documentation of `booktabs` has a lot to say on this subject and the package can be used to implement these recommendations.

For example:

[image: booktabs version]

However, `booktabs` seems to disagree with `revtex` so I had to switch to `article` for demonstration purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cCCC}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & K & H\\\midrule
      A & a & 1& 4\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
      B & b & 2 & 5\\\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}& 3 & 6\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In any case, if you are submitting to a journal or conference and they want a particular style, you are stuck with it and typographic aesthetics is irrelevant. (Although the documentation suggests that you should perhaps be using `revtex`'s versions of these commands in relevant places. Without, naturally, loading `booktabs`, which would mess them up.)

Comment: Super good. You are super professional. Let me learn it.

Comment: Is "booktab" comparable to  revtex4?

Comment: @Idear Do you mean is it compatible? No. As I said in the answer, they won't work together. So you can't have the enhancements of `booktabs` if you need to use `revtex4` :(.