# How to use booktabs in REVTex4 / REVTex4-1

Tags: tables, rules, arrays, multicolumn, data-structures

I wish to type this table in REVTeX; however, the code below does not work for `\documentclass{revtex4}`. (It does work for the `article` document class, though.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cCCC}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & K & H\\\midrule
      A & a & 1& 4\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
      B & b & 2 & 5\\\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}& 3 & 6\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The code is from the source of [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/221041/extending-a-line-in-the-table/221043#221043). Thanks to the generous cfr.

Answer (score 17):

**Update** This answer addresses a workaround for revtex4-1 which is not needed with current releases (revtex4-2)

---

booktabs sets the default widths in a font dependent way (`em` units) but it seems that revtex does not set up the font until `\begin{document}` so you need to delay setting the rule widths via the `\AtBeginDocument` directive shown below.

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{array,mathtools,amssymb,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \heavyrulewidth=.08em
  \lightrulewidth=.05em
  \cmidrulewidth=.03em
  \belowrulesep=.65ex
  \belowbottomsep=0pt
  \aboverulesep=.4ex
  \abovetopsep=0pt
  \cmidrulesep=\doublerulesep
  \cmidrulekern=.5em
  \defaultaddspace=.5em
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cCCC}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & K & H\\\midrule
      A & a & 1& 4\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
      B & b & 2 & 5\\\cmidrule(lr){1-4}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}& 3 & 6\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the purpose for this paragraph "\AtBeginDocument{...}" ? Where should I input this?

Comment: To avoid the duplicated code, couldn't one just do `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{booktabs}}` (also removing `booktabs` from the `\usepackage` on line 2, of course)?

Comment: This is overwriting `revtex4`'s own definition of commands such as `\toprule`. If this is for submission somewhere requiring the use of `revtex4`, I doubt this is a good idea at all.

Comment: @Idear as I say above, it sets the lengths later. You put it exactly as in the code above which if you run it should produce a table with rules

Comment: @cfr not really revtex doesn't alter the definitions of the rules, it's just that booktabs sets the rules assuming the fonts are set up which is not the case here. standard latex rules are set in terms of `pt` units so do not have the problem.

Comment: But it defines `\toprule` etc., right? So loading `booktabs` overwrites those definitions.

Comment: @cfr oh so it does, sorry: `> \toprule=macro:
->\hline \hline .`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle After these comments, it's hard to figure out what's the right way to proceed and whether the definitions get overwritten...

Answer (score 2):

This problem was already solved in RevTeX 4.2e (released October 5, 2020)

https://journals.aps.org/revtex

Comment: You are not wrong, but your answer mentions `revtex4-2`, but OP uses the deprecated `revtex4` (so it doesn't really answer the original question).  Nothing was changed in this area in RevTeX (and there are no plans to update RevTeX 4 and 4.1 in this regard in the future)